# NodeJS Async method returning undefined but method exits

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mongoose, async-await

I am having some issues with my code. Whenever I attempt to call my async method,  in another async method, I get an error of undefined. Please how do I resolve this?

Here is a snippert of my code

```
public async createInvoice(req: Request res: Response) {
    try{
        const { body } = req.body
        const {searchQuery} = req.query;
        const invoice = new Invoice({
          ...body,
          invoiceNumber: await this.serialInvoiceNumber(searchQuery), //THIS GIVES UNDEFINED ERROR
        });
    await invoice.save();
    console.log("mongodb", invoice);
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return res.status(400).json({
        message: "Something went wrong",
        error: error,
      });
    }
}

public async serialInvoiceNumber(searchQuery: string) {
    try {
      const totalCount = (await Invoice.countDocuments({ creator: searchQuery })) + 1;
      const invoiceNumber = utils.helpers.generateInvoiceNumber(totalCount); //this just formates the invoice number, not an async function and not the source of the problem
      return invoiceNumber;
    } 
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return "error"
    }
  }
```

The error I get is this:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'serialInvoiceNumber')`

I need to extract serialInvoiceNumber  because other functions need that value

Comment: Would be good to have the stack trace too.

Comment: @Mohamed Sohail when you say stack trace, do you mean the error?

Comment: The error says `this` is undefined. How are you calling `createInvoice` exactly?

Comment: To access 'this' inside a method you need to bind this to the function inside the constructor of your class. ( yourfunction.bind(this) inside the constructor )

Comment: @NicolasMenettrier thanks, your solution solved the problem. @robertklep, you are right, the way I called ```createInvoice``` was the problem.